# Java monitors and thread concurrency

Tags: java, arrays, multithreading, concurrency

I'm trying to build simple multithreading application. But I'm confused about Java monitors. I have many threads that want to format with their data one array. So for example I have Supermarket Threads (data of the thread is in txt file) So first thread have these product (Milk, Cheese, Chocolate) and country code for each product 1,2, 3

```
    SupermarketA
    Milk 1
    Cheese 2
    Chocolate 3
    SupermarketB
    Yogurt 1
    Orangle 2
    Bannana 3
    Tea 7
    Kiwi 9
```

and I want to format array that has to fields (country_code and count)
So my array should look like that

```
Country_code count
1              2
2              2
3              2
7              1
9              1
```

Code

```
public class SortedArray{
        private int num = 0; // num is country code
        private int count = 0;
}
```

So here's my **monitor** class

```
 public class SingleArray {
        private SortedArray[] array;
        private int arrayIndex;
        private static final int MAX_SIZE = 5;

    public SingleArray() {
        array = new SortedArray[MAX_SIZE];
        arrayIndex = 0;
        initArray();
    }

    private void initArray() {
        for (int i = 0; i < MAX_SIZE; i++) {
            array[i] = new SortedArray();
        }
    }

    public synchronized void inc(){
        awaitUnderMax();
        notifyAll();
    }

    private void awaitUnderMin(){
        while (arrayIndex == 0) try {
            wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public synchronized void dec(){
        awaitUnderMin();
        notifyAll();
    }

    public void add(ArrayList<Integer> count){
        for (int i = 0; i < count.size(); i++) {
            singleArray.inc();
            int num = count.get(i);
            if (singleArray.arrayIndex == 0) { // if array is empty add value to it
                singleArray.array[0].num = num;
                singleArray.array[0].count++;
                singleArray.arrayIndex++;
            } else {
                if (!isThere(num)) { // if num is a new value to array
                    singleArray.inc();
                    int index1 = singleArray.arrayIndex;
                    if (num > singleArray.array[index1 - 1].num) {
                        singleArray.inc();
                        singleArray.array[index1].num = num;
                        singleArray.inc();
                        singleArray.array[index1].count++;
                        singleArray.inc();
                        singleArray.arrayIndex++;

                        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " first " + singleArray.array[index1].num);
                    } else if (num < singleArray.array[index1 - 1].num) { // jei num mazesne uz paskutinia masyvo reiksme
                        int index = index1 - 1 < 0 ? index1 : index1 - 1;
                        while (index > 0 && num < singleArray.array[index].num) {
                            index--;
                        }
                        if (index != singleArray.arrayIndex) {
                            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " sec " + singleArray.array[index].num);
                            singleArray.array = addPos(singleArray.array, index + 1, num);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public boolean isThere(int number){
        for(int i=0; i<singleArray.arrayIndex; i++){
            singleArray.inc();
            if(number == singleArray.array[i].num){
                singleArray.array[i].count++;
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    private void awaitUnderMax(){
        while (arrayIndex >= MAX_SIZE) try {
            wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public synchronized void removeValue(int number, int howManyItems){
        for(int i=0; i<arrayIndex; i++){
            dec();
            if(number == array[i].num){
                int numberToDelete = array[i].count - howManyItems >= 0 ? howManyItems : array[i].count;
                if(array[i].count >= numberToDelete){
                    array[i].count -= numberToDelete;
                }
                if(array[i].count == 0){
                    deleteItem(i);
                }
            }
            if(array[i].count == 0){
                deleteItem(i);
            }
        }
    }
```

Each thread call `add(ArrayList<Integer> count)` method
So basically what add method does:

1. Find place where to insert new value (dependng if new value is greater or lower than a previous)
2. call `isThere(int num)` method that check if new value is already in array (if so  increment count `singleArray.array[i].count++`) otherwise add new value to array
3. If array is full `arrayIndex == MAX_SIZE` wait current thread for other threads to decrement `arrayIndex` (this is oly one part of code I also have other threads that based on county code decrement array)

**So the biggest problem is that multiplethreads need to update single array at the same time** (I know that adding `synchronized` keyword to add method should solve this problem but it only let one thread to run this method at once!) So sometimes all works fine, but sometimes I get really starnge results (for example that country code is 0 (**That is imposible!!!**) and sometimes new values is placed in wrong array posiitons). Also I think that `semaphores` should solve this problem, but is it possible to do that with `monitors`? Thank's for the answers.

EDIT v2
to @Elyasin

```
 public Thread[] setUpShopsBuilderThreads(){
        int size = data.getSize();
        ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> a = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> b = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>> c = new ArrayList<>();
        Thread[] threads = new Thread[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            int tmp = data.getIndex(i);
            int range = i + 1 < size ? data.getIndex(i + 1) : data.getWaresSize();
            ArrayList<String> name = new ArrayList<>();
            ArrayList<Integer> count = new ArrayList<>();
            ArrayList<Double> price = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int j = tmp; j < range; j++) {
                name.add(data.getName(j));
                count.add(data.getCount(j));
                price.add(data.getPrice(j));
            }
            a.add(name);
            b.add(count);
            c.add(price);
        }

        procesas_1 p1 = new procesas_1(a.get(0), b.get(0), c.get(0));
        procesas_2 p2 = new procesas_2(a.get(1), b.get(1), c.get(1));
        procesas_3 p3 = new procesas_3(a.get(2), b.get(2), c.get(2));
        procesas_4 p4 = new procesas_4(a.get(3), b.get(3), c.get(3));
        procesas_5 p5 = new procesas_5(a.get(4), b.get(4), c.get(4));

        Thread worker1 = new Thread(p1);
        Thread worker2 = new Thread(p2);
        Thread worker3 = new Thread(p3);
        Thread worker4 = new Thread(p4);
        Thread worker5 = new Thread(p5);

        threads[0] = worker1;
        threads[1] = worker2;
        threads[2] = worker3;
        threads[3] = worker4;
        threads[4] = worker5;

        return threads;
    }

public static void main(String[] args) {
        Starter start = new Starter();
        start.read();
        start.printShopsData();
        start.printUserData();

        Thread[] builderThreads = start.setUpShopsBuilderThreads();

        for(int i=0; i<builderThreads.length; i++){
            builderThreads[i].start();
        }
}
```

Comment: I would have thought the `add` method should have been synchronized?

Comment: As you mentioned *(this is oly one part of code I also have other threads that based on county code decrement array)*, I would suggest to declare the variables *arrayIndex* and *array* as **volatile**.

Comment: `synchronized` methods do not solve your problem. but you don't provide enough information, so that one can write an elaborate answer. one can only take your code and improve it and show you the way to do under assumptions. provide more code please (country, etc.). and why do you think `synchronized` methods solve your problem? did you check if you can run into a deadlock (i think you should)?  would it be possible to use a another data structure for you (priority queues/heaps e.g.)?  `semaphores` might solve it, but we need more code.

Comment: take the time to help us understand and we take the time to help you solve your problem.

Comment: @Elyasin I think that `synchronized ` metod add should solve my problem (but that isn't the way I want to do that) because then only one thread at time can write to array also I edited my post

Comment: You don't call classes Array if they aren't arrays or contain no arrays. Period. Your naming needs improvements.

Comment: `synchronized` roughly means that this method is atomic and avoids interleave. no more, no less. in particular, it does not control execution order. can you provide your `main` function/test cases?

Comment: Either, you guard *every* access to a resource (e.g. using `synchronized`) or the protection is *worthless*. Point. Besides that, your code is incomplete and so chaotic that you should think about writing correct single-threaded code first.

Answer (score 0):

what about using the concurrent safe datasets java already provides?

if you want it sorted, this one looks it might work for you:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListSet.html

just add it as in a normal Collection